# How Can I Import an Existing Github Project to Android Studio 3.0?

Tags: android, git, android-studio, github

I wanted to import an existing project from github, first of all
Android Studio told

> "Can't Find git.exe"

I installed Github for windows
After Installing I made a path variable for windows, but again android studio didn't recognize the git.exe afterwards in Android Studio setting I found a preference for path of git.exe
I set the path to

> C:/Users/Home/AppData/Local/Github...

It has a Test button, Test Result was OK
But when I wanted to import project Studio Given the following error
Clone Failed : Unable to find remote helper for '***https***'
I removed "s" of from https in URL but again
Even it didn't connect to github 
Given Error
Clone Failed : Unable to find remote helper for '***http***'
I made a clone at local disk
Again,
Clone Failed : Unable to find remote helper for '***file***'
The URL was :

> file:///C:/Users/Home/Documents/Source-Code

I'm searching all around the world but I can't find the solution
I would be appreciated If anybody can solve my question.

Comment: Did you restart Android Studio after installing Git?

Comment: @Zoe Thanks a lot helped is Working

Answer (score 0):

Restart Android Studio after installing Git.

Path updates aren't registered by Android Studio (or CMD for that matter) if it's running as it doesn't query the system again every time you need to access something.